# Crashing App with 'Accessing object of type which has been invalidated or deleted' error message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am using Realm as the database for my react native project.

I am getting an error like 'Accessing object of type XXX which has been invalidated or deleted' when I try to delete an object from the realmDB.
The object gets deleted however the app shows error.

After some research I found out **isValid()** property as a solution. But how does it work with my code below and what is the real reason behind the issue?

**DBScheme**

```
export const deleteNewTemplateScheme = newTemplateObjectId => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
Realm.open(NewTemplateScheme).then(realm => {
    realm.write(() => {
        let deletingNewTemplateObject = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(NEW_TEMPLATE_SCHEMA, newTemplateObjectId);
        realm.delete(deletingNewTemplateObject);
        resolve();
      });
  }).catch((error) => reject(error));;
});
```

**Fetching**

```
deleteNewTemplateScheme(this.state.content.id).then(()=> {
Alert.alert('Deleted');
}).catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert('Failed to delete todoList: ', error);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution myself. It seems that if you pass an object to navigation or a new component as props, delete this object (while the object is still in the navigation stack or new component), - it will trigger this error.

What I did earlier was creating a new component and pass the realm objects as props, now what I did is create the same component in the parent class Itself(Hence, no need of passing props). So it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably deleted object referenced another comp or param. You can check it